# Django throws error no. 10053 when receiving POST from jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, http

I'm trying out jQuery to send POST and GET requests to Django.

So far only GET is recognized, and POST I will get errors, and although GET works I cannot get the individual fields that I send to my Django app.

So I wonder what's the problem, and how do I get POST to work?

**views.py**

```
def xhr_test(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'GET':
            message = "Hello GET Ajax"
            print request.GET
            print "hello"
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            message = "Hello POST Ajax"
            print request.POST
    else:
        message = "Hello"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

**template**

```
<html>  
<head>  
  <title>Ajax with jQuery Example</title>  
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/jquery.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/JavaScript">  
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#generate").click(function() {
      $.get("/ajax_fetch/xhr_test", function(data) {
      // alert(data);
      });
    });

    $("#generate_post").click(function() {
      $.post("/ajax_fetch/xhr_test", {
        name: "Monty"
      }, function(data) {
          alert(data)
      });
    });
  });
  </script>  
<style type="text/css">  
    #wrapper {  
      width: 240px;  
      height: 80px;  
      margin: auto;  
      padding: 10px;  
      margin-top: 10px;  
      border: 1px solid black;  
      text-align: center;  
    }  
  </style>  
</head>  
<body>  
  <div id="wrapper">  
    <div id="quote"><p> </p></div> 
    <form method="get">
      <p><input type="text" name="user" /></p>
      <p><input type="submit" id="generate" value="Generate!" /></p>
    </form>

    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
      <p><input type="text" name="user" /></p>
      <p><input id="generate_post" type="submit" value="Click" /></p>
    </form>
  </div
</body>  
</html>
```

**Error trace**

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 1625)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 310, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 56
, in __init__
    BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 641, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "c:\python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 694, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "c:\python27\lib\socket.py", line 301, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in y
ur host machine
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I don't want to adjust the question. So post my solution to the problem as an answer instead. Here's the modified files

**template**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#generate").click(function() {
      $.get("/ajax_fetch/xhr_test",$("form:first").serialize(), function(data) {
          alert(data);
      });
      return false
    });
  });

<form>{% csrf_token %}
      <p><input type="text" name="user" /></p>
      <p><input type="text" name="name" /></p>
      <p><input type="submit" id="generate" value="Generate!" /></p>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def xhr_test(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'GET':
            message = "Hello GET Ajax"
            message += " "+request.GET.get('user', '')
            message += " "+request.GET.get('name', '')
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            message = "Hello POST Ajax"
            print "hello"
            message += " "+request.POST.get('user', '')
    else:
        message = "Hello"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<input id="generate_post" type="submit" value="Click" />
```

to

```
<input id="generate_post" type="button" value="Click" />
```

(Change `submit` to `button`)

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. But why does `type="submit"` cause this error?!

Answer (score 0):

There is a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896018/django-development-server-not-handling-ajax-request)

Perhaps the answer is in `settings.APPEND_SLASH` setting, that redirects `/ajax_fetch/xhr_test` to `/ajax_fetch/xhr_test/`. Try to post data to URL with slash at the end

Comment: that's not my problem though. Anyway I solved it after some medling